# aws elastic beanstalk with spring boot app

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed my spring boot app with this tutorial https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/devops/deploying-a-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk/, set the server port door to 5000 with enviroment varible, and it's work fine.
 But some time latter without any request when i try to post our get some resource i take a timeout error:

---

2017/08/26 02:19:24 [error] 12955#0: *15 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.2.223, server: , request: "GET /api/motoristas HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/motoristas", host: "vaptuberjjaerp-env.e5y5w4fa2q.sa-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com"

---

and if i try to access api documentation link it works fine: http://vaptuberjjaerp-env.e5y5w4fa2q.sa-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/swagger-ui.html

What is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing for certain but this sounds like your documentation might just be static content that is generated at build time. If this is the case then it would still be accessible if the Java process for your app died. In this case the rest of your app would be unavailable. I recommend checking that the app your process runs in is still active and running.

Comment: yes app is running, if i try to get without authorization for example the app return 401, our not found with spring error msg when try to get a invalid resource.